# Unable to create an instance of extension {CLASS NAME}

Tags: controller, controller-extension

I'm getting this error, i'm sure I what this means. I couldn't find anything helpful anywhere.

Comment: Can you explain more in details please and show some code if possible ?

Comment: Enable debug log and check what going on during class initiation (i.e. constructor)